# MySQL: how to run shell command from .SQL script file

Tags: mysql, sql, shell, command

Running with MySQL 5.6.36 on Windows 10, I am writing a script in .sql file.
I need to run some shell command (in this case to concatenate two files).

How can i do it?

I tried this but it gives "compilation error":

```
\! ls
```

It says:

> Syntax error: '\' escape operator  is not valid input at this position

Comment: why do you think that it is possible to call shell from sql?

Comment: What operating system are you using?.

Comment: i am using Windows 10 with MySQL 5.6.36.
The question was updated as well

Comment: `The system (\!) command works only in Unix.`, see [4.5.1.2 mysql Commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html). Try using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), see [Windows 10 Installation Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide).

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the error:

File: `/path/to/file/test.sql`

```bsh
SELECT VERSION();

SELECT 'system' `system`;
system ls -al myDir

SELECT '\\!';
\! ls -al myDir
```

MySQL Command Line:

```sql
mysql> \. /path/to/file/test.sql
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.11    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+--------+
| system |
+--------+
| system |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

total 0
dr--------  2 user user  10 Jan 12 00:00 .
dr-------- 23 user user 280 Jan 13 23:00 ..
+----+
| \! |
+----+
| \! |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

total 0
dr--------  2 user user  10 Jan 12 00:00 .
dr-------- 23 user user 280 Jan 13 23:00 ..
```

Comment: Can it be related to the version?
I still see the error:

| VERSION()  |
| 5.6.36-log |

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'system ls -al myDir

SELECT '\\!'' at line 1
ERROR:
Unknown command '\!'.
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\! ls -al myDir' at line 1

Comment: @SamerAamar: This may be related to the version of your operating system.

Comment: maybe it is related to operating system. issue was not resolved yet, so i had to implement it in total other way. Thanks!